# Unexpected cast to AppCompatButton: layout tag was Button

Tags: android, android-studio, casting, android-appcompat, lint

From [AppCompatButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html) reference page:

> This will automatically be used when you use Button in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

I'm casting a normal `Button` to `AppCompatButton`, so that I can use `setSupportBackgroundTintList` method:

```
AppCompatButton button = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.normalButton);
button.setSupportBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(tintColor));
```

It builds and runs without any problem, but Android Studio 1.4 gives me the annoying red highlight on casting line:

> Unexpected cast to AppCompatButton: layout tag was Button

Any ideas?

Comment: it is probably a bug in the ide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the IDE type checking - Button is direct ancestor of AppCompatButton, so casting to AppCompatButton should be okay. I believe you can safely call it like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.normalButton);
((AppCompatButton)button).setSupportBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(tintColor));
```

or better

```
((TintableBackgroundView)button).setSupportBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(tintColor));
```

If you use Butterknife, everything works as expected without any warning:

```
@Bind(R.id.normalButton)
AppCompatButton button;
```