# Crash when using API < 21 navigationView.setBackgroundTintList

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am having a serious problem in my project and it is affecting several users using android <21.
I change the colors of my navigationView however when using android <21 the application throws an exception.
Larger versions work normally.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
navigationView.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, ThemeUtil.getThemeList().get(mTheme).getPrimaryColor())));
}else {
((TintableBackgroundView)navigationView).setSupportBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(tintColor));
}
```

Problem is in this line:

```
((TintableBackgroundView) navigationView) .setSupportBackgroundTintList (ColorStateList.valueOf (tintColor));
```

How can I use setSupportBackgroundTintList in navigationView?

Comment: Whats the exception?!

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.NavigationView cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.TintableBackgroundView

Comment: Why do you think that `NavigationView` is a `TintableBackgroundView`?

Comment: I wanted to take an example and just found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495164/unexpected-cast-to-appcompatbutton-layout-tag-was-button/33495477

Comment: That's for specifically `AppCompatButton`, which does implement `TintableBackgroundView`. `NavigationView` does not, however. For versions prior to Lollipop, you'll have to set the tint list directly on the background `Drawable`. You can do something like is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259711), substituting `DrawableCompat.setTintList()` for `DrawableCompat.setTint()`.

Comment: Mike, there is no "setBackgroundTint" method for android smaller API 21
How to do this? I think I should use "setSupportBackgroundTintList", but I'm not sure how to apply this to my NavigationView

Comment: I linked to a specific example – https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259711. What problems are you having with it?

Comment: In this example it is using `setBackground` and not `setBackgroundTintList`

`setBackground` Changes the color of the menu, `setBackgroundTintList` changes the color of the title

Comment: mike look -> https://imgur.com/a/t76dDtm

Comment: "In this example it is using `setBackground` and not `setBackgroundTintList`" – Yes, that's why you apply the tint list to the background `Drawable`. "`setBackground` Changes the color of the menu, `setBackgroundTintListchanges` the color of the title" – I'm not sure what you're saying there. What do you mean by menu, exactly? And what title? I can't really make out that image.

Comment: The color is dark gray, should look blue as the whole menu. Please see the image again.

Comment: I don't know how you're doing that, exactly, but I just ran a quick test, and both methods work the same for me. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JwKVx3HiCqelWxi_ot-tGLrNFWC8_4Ra/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: That way you said it did not work! But I managed to do it successfully like this:: `navigationView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, ThemeUtil.getThemeList().get(mTheme).getPrimaryColor()));`

Comment: Then you did something wrong, because that example is equivalent to `setBackgroundTintList()`. Furthermore, why didn't you just set the background color to begin with? If it's a solid color – which I can't really tell from that image – tinting it is rather pointless. You don't even need to do a version check. Just call `setBackgroundColor()`.

Comment: Yes I agree! Is that before I only used setBackgroundTintList, but to know that user with android with API <21 was having problems I put the version check. It stopped giving problem but the menu was still in problem.
Important that it worked, thank you very much for your time in trying to work out and sorry for something.